# Connection error when using Tableau Desktop 2021.4 to Tableau Server - Authentication error via Google?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau Server login issue that's addressed on this official [Tableau page](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_config.htm) and I don't think I'm literate enough to change anything with SSL.

The issue happened as soon as I upgraded from Tableau Desktop 2021.3 version to the latest 2021.4.3, every time when I'm trying to signin to our external partner's Tableau Server to save my workbook, it produces this code as soon as I enter login info via Google "Tableau created this window to authenticate. It is now safe to close it." on http://127.0.0.1:50436/Callback

Error code on Tableau Desktop 2021.4.3

```
An error occurred while communicating with the data source
Authentication failed.
Error Code: 84223ADA
Unable to connect to Tableau Server.
SSLHandshakeException
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

If I try to connect to the server without changing anything on Tableau Desktop 2021.3, it's working perfectly fine. What would be the issue at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Tableau Server Version is older than Tableau Desktop, that way they are incompatible: "You can publish workbooks and data sources to Tableau Server if the version of Tableau Server is the same or newer than the version of Tableau Desktop."
Source: https://help.tableau.com/current/desktopdeploy/en-us/desktop_deploy_compatibility.htm

Comment: I am not joining to Tableau server and working on Desktop version only, can you explain why there is a reference to Tableau server? Also I tried a bunch of versions (2022-1-0; 2021-4-5; 2021-4-3; 2021-4-2; 2021-3-9), but it seems that after upgrade I am getting the same error: 84223ADA. Also I am attempting to connect to **Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2** so no Tableau server involved. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with 2021.4.  See item number 1366751 on the Tableau Known Issues page: https://www.tableau.com/support/known-issues.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.